# Replacing CountDownTimer with Handler and Runnable for better performance

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, android-handler

I've got game based on CountDownTimer, which is continuously repeating countdowns. This countDown is counting time for user to react on some action related to `number`, if user reacts `onFinish()` is called by some `clickListener` or by itself if the time was up. Depending of `succesCondition()`,  method `success` or `fail` is called and those methods are defining if game is still running.

OnCreate

```
loop = gameLoop(time).start();
```

MainActivity

```
public CountDownTimer gameLoop(int time){
    return new CountDownTimer(time, time+100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (!Conditions.succesCondition(number)) {
                success();
            } else {
                fail();
            }
        }
    };
}

public void success() {
    loop.cancel();
    scoreCount++;
    animation.start();
}

public void fail(){
   loop.cancel();
}
```

However this timer runs on Main thread and that provides well known issue `skipped xx frames, your app might be doing too much work on its main thread` and I found that this is common issue for `CountDownTimer` and replacing it with `Handler` is a solution.

I can't put this timer in `AsyncTask` because it performs mainly UI related tasks (TextViews, TextSwitcher, some progressBar etc. in `success()` method. I didn't put that in code in those methods for more clean view of the main problem. I'm trying to reconstruct `CountDownTimer`- like concept with handler and runnable to replace my Timer, but I'm actually stuck with nothing. As you can see I'm using only `onFinish` method, `onTick` is not necessary.

Comment: it's not that easy to perform handler with similar behavior to countDownTimer

Comment: No, I don't know, I've seen countDownTimer class before but I couldn't figure out how to rewrite it by myself

Comment: so what is unclear in a `Handler` you got? what methods calls are hard to understand?

Comment: It's not like something is unclear, but if I'll do this just by rewriting timer class then there won't be any difference in performance

Comment: so `CountDownTimer` is not a culprit but your `onTick` methods is doing too much work on the UI thread

Comment: onTick is empty, nothing is there

Comment: how often are you calling `gameLoop`? also your `CountDownTimer(time, time+100)` is pointless - check the documentation for both parameters - what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: I know this is pointless but I had something to put here, I actually didn't understood well the second parameter... For more clearence this is my game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pnpdevelopers.patryk.threes. gameLoop.start is called every time you get score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I finally figured out how to handle it with handler (hehe):

```
public void startGameAction() {

    //My game actions

    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = () -> {
        if (!Conditions.succesCondition(number)) {
            success();
        } else {
            fail();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,time);
}

public void success(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler = null;

        scoreCount++;
        //other stuff
        startGameAction();
    }

 private void fail() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    //other stuff
}
```

onCreate only startGame call, handler and runnable defined as class fields

```
startGameAction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may handle this situation using `AsyncTask` as well overriding the `onProgressUpdate` method.

Here's [an example](https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/) about how you can achieve the behaviour to interact with your main thread from `AsyncTask`. The example shows the update of a download which can be easily transformed to your specific problem of timer.

**Update**

> In my case almost all code would be in onProgressUpdate, would it
>   still make any sense?

No, your code will not be in `onProgressUpdate`. The `onProgressUpdate` method will only be updating your timer in your UI. As far as I could understand, the success and the fail will be triggered based on user action as well. Then those actions are triggered, you can stop the `AsyncTask` to update your timer as well. You just need to `AsyncTask` to update the timer value time to time.

You will get a callback in your `Activity` when the `AsyncTask` finishes. See the `mNotificationHelper.completed();` function in the above example. When you are notified in your `Activity` when the timer finishes, you might then execute the following task there.

```
public void completed()    {
    if (!Conditions.succesCondition(number)) {
        success();
    } else {
        fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case almost all code would be in onProgressUpdate, would it still make any sense?

Comment: Not only timer is related to UI thread, I've got animations, textViews and so on which are updating on every countdown which is repeating every 3 seconds

Comment: Yes, those needs to be updated in `onProgressUpdate` which are related to the countdown.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a combination of `java.util.Timer`, `java.util.TimerTask` and `Activity.runOnUiThread()`. First create a `Timer` and call one of its `schedule...()`methods. Any action that needs to be done on the main (ui) thread can be wrapped in `runOnUiThread(() -> { ...})`. Be sure to call `cancel()` on `TimerTask` and `Timer` if those objects are no longer needed. Cancelling the `Timer` cancels the `TimerTask` as well.

Here is how this may look like:

```
public class TimerTaskActivity extends Activity {

    Timer timer;
    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timertask);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    ....
                });
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 2000, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timer.cancel();
    }
}
```